# Include AlpineJS variable in request from Laravel Blade form

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I have added a 'tags' field to an existing form.  The form is a standard html form in Laravel blade.

The tags field is using 'Tailwind / Alpine Tag Multi Select' from https://codepen.io/atomgiant/pen/QWjWgKz - which works beautifully on the front end.

On submission of the form, 'tagsList' is `null`.

How do I pass the value from the tags field in to the form?

I've tried setting the name of the field to 'tags', 'tagsList', 'textInput' - still comes through as null.

I've tried changing from `@tags-update="console.log('tags updated', $event.detail.tags)"` to `@tags-update="tagsList = $event.detail.tags)"` and adding `let tagsList = []` to the script  - still comes through as null.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved by updating `@tags-update` from console log to populate tagsList variable.

```
<div x-data @tags-update="{ tagsList: $event.detail.tags }" data-tags='[{{ $tags }}]' class="mt-1 flex">
```

And adding a hidden field with the x-model set to `tags`

```
<input type="hidden" x-model="tags" id="tagsList" name="tagsList[]" multiple="multiple"/>
```